# Xamarin ios, sqlite returning 0 columns in a table

Tags: ios, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios

When I try to create a table in sqlite, the application fails because the table I want to create has zero columns, the weird thing is that I also create like 8 more tables, and those tables work fine without error, I have been reading some posts and in one said that if I change the build options to "Link SDK Frameworks only it will work, but the problem is that when I do that this happens:

> /Users/MacDeveloper/Documents/MDC/FrontEnd/MDC.Presentation.IOS/MTOUCH:
>   Error MT2002: Failed to resolve
>   "System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase" reference from "System,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"
>   (MT2002) (MDC.Presentation.IOS)

I change the link behavior to Link all but I get the same error, also in Dont Link I get this error below:

> /Users/MacDeveloper/Documents/MDC/FrontEnd/MDC.Presentation.IOS/MTOUCH:
>   Error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly
>   '/Users/MacDeveloper/Documents/MDC/FrontEnd/MDC.Presentation.IOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/mtouch-cache/64/Build/MDC.Business.dll'
>   (MT3001) (MDC.Presentation.IOS)

the dll in the error is from another library imported to the project, that was made with Visual Studio.

Is there a solution to this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because some of your assemblies are compiled against the MS .NET framework **full** desktop profile.

This is not what's shipped with Xamarin's products. The BCL is a subset, called **mobile**, that is optimized for size. That removes some types like all of `System.Configuration` (both namespaces and the assembly).

Your first error makes it clear the assembly is using a type that does not exists

> System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase

and the assembly fully qualified name starts with

> System, Version=4.0.0.0

which is not what Xamarin ships, it would be `System, Version=2.1.0.0 ...` the same version as used by Silverlight (on which the original mobile profile is based upon).

Your second error is likely similar but happens at a later stage (because you disabled the linker). In that case the AOT compiler sees call to methods that does not exists and simply cannot generate correct code.

The solution is to rebuild your code against the Xamarin SDK assemblies (the BCL that ships with the product) or against one of the PCL profiles that Xamarin's support.